# Azure file share can not connect using powershell script?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-virtual-machine

I am using below command for mount file on windows azure vm :

```
$connectTestResult = Test-NetConnection -ComputerName aaadcstore.file.core.windows.net -Port 445
if ($connectTestResult.TcpTestSucceeded) {
    # Save the password so the drive will persist on reboot
    cmd.exe /C "cmdkey /add:`"aaadcstore.file.core.windows.net`" /user:`"Azure\*******`" /pass:`"*****************`""
    # Mount the drive
    New-PSDrive -Name Z -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\aaadcstore.file.core.windows.net\amazefileshare" -Persist
} else {
    Write-Error -Message "Unable to reach the Azure storage account via port 445. Check to make sure your organization or ISP is not blocking port 445, or use Azure P2S VPN, Azure S2S VPN, or Express Route to tunnel SMB traffic over a different port."
}
```

But my connection TcpTest not Succeeded I have open 445 using NSG but still not working.

Comment: Can you just run `Test-NetConnection -ComputerName aaadcstore.file.core.windows.net -Port 445` in PowerShell console on the VM and share the output?

Comment: @Gaurav o/p : WARNING: Name resolution of amazedcstore.file.core.windows.net failed -- Status: No such host is known


ComputerName   : amazedcstore.file.core.windows.net
RemoteAddress  :
InterfaceAlias :
SourceAddress  :
PingSucceeded  : False

Comment: Thanks. And what happens when you run the same command from your local computer?

Comment: From Local o/p        WARNING: TCP connect to (20.60.128.136 : 445) failed                                                                    WARNING: Ping to 20.60.128.136 failed with status: TimedOut                                                 

ComputerName           : amazedcstore.file.core.windows.net
RemoteAddress          : 20.60.128.136
RemotePort             : 445
InterfaceAlias         : Wi-Fi 3
SourceAddress          : 192.168.1.102
PingSucceeded          : False
PingReplyDetails (RTT) : 0 ms
TcpTestSucceeded       : False

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message, probably it's a DNS issue on your Azure VM.

You can verify if you use the Azure-provided DNS server in the Azure VNet where Azure VM located. If you use a custom DNS server and make sure it should be able to resolve the Azure file share FQDN. You need to restart the Azure VM to update the DNS server settings.

[image]

Comment: Given solution worked for me like charm.....Thanks.